# Querying many to many relationship

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Every article I need to solve my problem seems to be in C# and I need a solution in VB.NET.

I'm using EF 6.0 with Database First model. Let me use the classic Customer product scenario to demonstrate my situation. In my database I have three tables Customer, Product and CustomerProduct. See  [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396321/Many-to-Many-relation-with-Entity-Framework-in-ASP) in this link as mine is exactly the same.

After I generate my model from the database, my entity model diagram shows that the CustomerProduct has disappeared as expected and the the model shows a many to many relationship between Customer and Product also as expected with navigational properties of Products in Customer and Customers in Product.

All I want to do is find the product related to a customer pull out some data from both tables namely CustName and ProductName.

The SQL I would use is:

```
SELECT c.CustName, p.ProductName FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN CustomerProduct cp on c.CustomerId = cp.CustomerId
INNER JOIN Product p on cp.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE c.CustomerId=101
```

I don't know how to use the Addresses navigational property to access the Address data in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You include them and then access them via the property in the Entity class.

```
Dim query = model.User.Include("Address").Include("UserAddressLink").Where(Function(o) o.UserId = 101).FirstOrDefault

If Not query Is Nothing Then
 Dim houseNumber = query.Address.HouseNo 'uses the navigation property
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response however unfortunately that doesn't work. I get the error "The EntityType 'model.User' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'UserAddressLink'." I'm not sure how I can link the UserAddressLink entity as it doesn't exist. It disappeared when I created the model and I only have the two navigational properties of Addresses in User and Users in Address.

Comment: You have to set up the relationship in the database then import the model based on DB, then you will see the navigation properties in the model.

Comment: You can also use Lambdas and strongly typed Includes, if you import the System.Data.Entity namespace, e.g. `model.User.Include(Function(U) U.Address).ToList`. But as @AlastairW points out, you must first update your model with your database relationships (assuming you've already constructed the latter).

Comment: I've completely re-edited the description to make it clearer as to what I am trying to achieve, I found a link that shows exactly my setup. My database relationships are exactly as I want them, everything is doing exactly what it should. The link should disappear and I should be able to use the navigational property to get the data I need without having to include the link table.

Comment: Thank you @InteXX I managed to worked it out from your solution in the end. I'll post the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to InteXX I managed to work it out. This is my whole solution

```
Using db as new CustProdEntities

Dim query = db.Customers.Include(Function(U) U.Products).ToList
txtCustomer.Text = query.First.CustName
txtProduct.Text query.First.Products.First.ProdName

End Using
```

The bit I was stuck on was having to filter twice to the Product data. I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do this but it works for now.